# Substrings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I'm translating an example from C to Objective-C and have a questions.

*C/C++ instruction:*

```
buffer[i].str = population[i1].str.substr(0, spos) + population[i2].str.substr(spos, esize - spos);
```

How can I translate the part .substr(0, spos)

Buffer and population are vector using .
str is a string variable
i, i1, i2, spos and esize are integer variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) methods.

You've got a lot of methods for creating substrings.
Mainly:

- substringFromIndex:
- substringWithRange:
- substringToIndex:

`.substr(0, spos)` may be translated to:

```
[ someString substringToIndex: spos ];
```

Note you will first need to convert your C++ string object to a NSString object.

Comment: Thanks. I missed these methods when i search they in Ingredients